# Couldn't able to see all the options in the drop-down menu after selecting one in React

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-hooks

I have student data. I want to filter and display names and IDs based on date. I can select the date but once I choose a date the dropdown menu shows only that particular date, not the other dates. I want to see all the dates whenever I click the input field. Could you please guide me on what I am doing wrong in my code?

```
const students = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Tobe",    
    jdate: "12/2/2021",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Nina",
    jdate: "15/2/2021",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Mike",
    jdate: "12/2/2021",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Scott",
    jdate: "14/2/2021",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Carlos",
    jdate: "13/2/2021",
  },
  
]

function App() {
const [filterStudent, setFilterStudent] = useState(students);
const[jDate, setJDate] = useState("")

  const dates = Array.from(
    new Set(filterStudent.map(st => st.jdate))
  )

    useEffect(() => {
    setFilterStudent(
      filterStudent.filter(st => {
        return (
          (!jDate || jDate === st.jdate) )
      })
    )
  }, [jDate])
 
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div>
      <select onChange={e => setJDate(e.target.value)} value={jDate}>
        <option value="" disabled default selected>
          Select Date
        </option>
        {dates.map(dt => {
          return <option key={dt}>{dt}</option>
        })}
      </select>      
      </div>
      <ul>
        {filterStudent.map(st => {
          const { name,  id, date} = st
          return (
            <li key={id}>
              <div>
                Name: <strong>{name}</strong>
              </div>              
              <div>ID: {id}</div>
              <div>Joining Date: {date}</div>
            </li>
          )
        })}
 
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image]
[image]

In the 2nd image, I want to see all the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Line36 : replace `students` instead of `filterStudent` :

```
  const dates = Array.from(new Set(students.map((st) => st.jdate)));
```

`filteredStudent's` dates just contains `selected date` but `students` array contains all of dates!!!
Is that what you want meant?

[show edit result](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-framework-k0odhz?file=/src/App.js:523-591)

Comment: i update the code  in line 46 :    ` students.filter((st) => {` : [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-framework-k0odhz?file=/src/App.js:523-591)

Comment: Yeah! I wanted the above what you stated! Thanks again.

Comment: If I'm rendering the data from API I'm facing the same problem. `const [filterStudent, setFilterStudent] = useState([]);
const[jDate, setJDate] = useState("")      useEffect(() => {
    protectedRequest(
      `/signals/${userInfo.id}/information`,
      "GET",
      session,
    )
      .then((response) => {
         const newInfo = response. data.data;
        setFilterStudent(newInfo);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  }, [userInfo]);    const dates = Array.from(new Set(filteredStudent.map((bt) => bt.date)));

Comment: Facing the same problem like above

Comment: please add more detail from your code

Comment: Last time I was accepting the data directly from students, but now I'm fetching student's information through API call. So I'm facing the same problem after API call  `  useEffect(() => {
    setFilterStudent(
      filterStudent.filter((bt) => {
        return !iDate || iDate === bt.date;
      }),
    );
  }, [iDate]);`

Comment: i will change code in  codesandbox

Comment: see modified code : https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-framework-k0odhz?file=/src/App.js:0-1788